# Ruby - Max number with the highest frequency

Tags: ruby

Based on the array:

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10]
```

I would like to get the answer **3**, because it is the highest number with the highest frequency.

I know how to get the highest frequency:

```
arr.max_by { |i| arr.count(i) }
```

And know how to get the highest number:

```
arr.max
```

The case is how to combine both.

The case is, I need to know which is the current round in a tournament, and for each match I have the corresponding round, but sometimes a match of latest rounds are played before (round 10 in array example), so I just can't get the highest number.

Comment: You are looking for the median. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, number  1 has the highest frequency in your example.

Comment: I added more information @bub

Comment: @eugen, but 3 is the highest number, although less frequently then 1.

Comment: @SérgioToledo 4 is the highest number, not 3 :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko but he wants the number with the heighest frequency then it is 1

Comment: I added more information in order to be clearer (I am trying to...)

Comment: Can you clarify two more things:  (1) Will the current round always have the maximum number of games played, always equal to previous completed rounds? It would seem not, because you might be half way through the current round? (2) Why can you not simply store and separately track the current round? As games can be played outside it, it appears to be a separately defined piece of data after all. It looks like you can derive a "maximum *completed* round" from your data, is that useful?

Comment: @SérgioToledo how do rounds and matches correlate to the numbers in your array?

Comment: @Neil, 1 - You're right, the current round could be in the half way. 2 - I'm just reading an API that gives me the matches data that have the matches round, that's why I have to do this calculation.

Comment: @Stefan, I have an array of matches and each one has its round number.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your answer could be `arr.max_by { |i| [arr.count(i), i] }`.